# Enabling the USBCFG on the USB to UART ic?

Tags: usb, uart, datasheet

I've gone over the data sheet, it says to refer to  Section 1.6.1.2, which I did but I cannot find any useful information regarding how to enable that pin, [datasheet](https://upverter.com/datasheet/592f89b4bf605760bc11af82ad44cdc3e4637272.pdf)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's in the MCP2200 Configuration utility. See figure 2-1.